# Calling SOAP webservice using java

Tags: java, web-services, http, soap

I am using the below code to invoke a soap based webservice. While invoking I need to check from the client side, whether the invocation was success or not. Need not wait for the response from the webservice.

Is there any response code or by any way, the client would know that the invocation was success and the payload passed was correct.

```
         url = new URL(webserviceURL);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String xmlInput =
            " <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n" +
            "   <soapenv:Body>\n" + bodyContent + "   </soapenv:Body>\n" + "</soapenv:Envelope>";
        byte[] buffer = new byte[xmlInput.length()];
        buffer = xmlInput.getBytes();
        bout.write(buffer);
        byte[] b = bout.toByteArray();
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(b.length));
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStream out = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(b);
        out.close();
```

Regards,
Stalin

Comment: it would be a lot easier if you use SOAP library and get WSDL document itself

Comment: My code should be generic in nature, not bound to any particular wsdl. I should be able to able to invoke any soap service. It only takes the webservice url and payload as the input.

Comment: yes i do understand what you are trying to do. HttpURLConnection is a good choose indeed, but the way soap services works is you need to mention SOAP_ACTION, SOAP_METHOD, SOAP_NAMESPACE. SOAP_URL, so it would be a best and easiest to chose, you have right now SOAP library

Comment: I hope, you are suggesting me to use javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection.call(SOAPMessage request,
                                     Object to) throws SOAPException  ??

Answer (score 0):

```
            SoapObject send = new SoapObject("Your NAMESPACE"," Your METHODS");
```

*// now add as many parameters you need to send it to your web service method or none if you don't have*

```
send.addProperty("intId", 0);



            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(send);

            envelope.dotNet = true;

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("Your SOAP_ADDRESS");
            androidHttpTransport.call("Your SOAP_ACTION", envelope);

            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            String s = result.toString();
```

make sure you do add ksop2 library to your project to use this,

you can gather information about *SOAP_ADDRESS*,*NAMESPACE*,*METHODS* and *SOAP_ADDRESS* from WSDL document provided to you just run it in browser